# Cut polylines at intersections in QGIS (or how many km road for each country)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, distance, intersection

I want to measure how many km a road stand on each country it intersect (i.e. how many km of the european road "E45" stand on Italy, Austria, Germany, and so on).

I have a polyline-shapefile with the "road" and a point-shapefile with the intersections of the "road" with the "nation-borders".

1) How I can cut automatically the road on each point?

2) How I can measure the distance on road between two consecutive point?

I'm trying to do it with QGIS.

Thanks,
ge.Ko

Answer (score 1):

if you also have to country boundaries in a shapefile, you could use those to clip (Vector\Geoprocessing Tools\Clip) based on the country. Or if you just want a total length value and don't need the shape itself, you could use the Analysis Tools\Sum Line Lengths tool to generate a length of each road in each country.